# Conda Environment not showing in JupyterLab Desktop

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have anaconda installed in the system with an environment named *ML_env* with python version 3.6.13. **JupyterLab Browser** runs smoothly on this environment with various machine learning libraries installed.

Recently, I installed ****JupyterLab desktop**** - Version 3.1.13-1. I wanted to change the kernel of the JupyerLab Desktop to the anaconda environment *ML_env*. However, I am not getting any options to change the kernel. Please find the attached screenshot.

Is there a way to change the kernel of  ****JupyterLab desktop**** to conda environment? Please help. [image: JupyterLab desktop Kernel change]

Comment: I have same issue. Seems like a major negative for users if this is not made more seamless. Aren't desktop apps supposed to be more "beginner friendly" than command line prompts.
  
I went through this whole rigmarole and still had nothing showing in JupyterLab Desktop:
`conda create -n myenv python=3.7
conda activate myenv
conda install -y -c conda-forge jupyterlab
conda install -y -c anaconda jupyter
conda install -y ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv`

Answer (score 0):

In the [bottom left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqxZW.png), change your environment to the python.exe that your conda environment is running on. Then, restart the desktop app and you should see your conda environments as kernel options.

Comment: Did not work for me. I see the conda environment now, but the kernel options have not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyterlab desktop can´t see new enviroments if you it doesn´t have ipython and other extra packets installed in the enviroment.
Here how create a zero ground conda enviroment for Ubuntu Linux:

Update conda

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

create a new enviroment

```
conda create -n ml_env
```

Activate enviroment

```
conda activate ml_env
```

For have a detactable enviroment (for jupyterlab desktop)

```
jupyter kernelspec list (see what kernels available you have)

ipython kernel install --user --name=python3 (to install kernel)
```

Install extra packets

```
conda install -c conda-forge -y "jupyterlab>=3.0.0"  (jupyter desktop could give the option to install it if you try to select the env manually)
```

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?

Comment: No, my own experience tryilng to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

this is now at the top right, where you can change the kernel from anaconda